# Simplifying a negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How do i simplify this negation, I seem to really struggle with these logical simplifications.

$\neg(p \land (q \lor r) \lor(\neg p\lor\neg q \lor r))$

Addition: how would this be?
 $\neg(p \land (q \lor r) \land (\neg p\lor\neg q \lor r))$

Comment: Are you missing some parentheses? I'm not sure how to parse $(A\land B \lor C)$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs It's pretty standard that $\wedge$ takes priority over $\vee$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs $\land$ has precedence over $\lor$.

Comment: Use the facts: $$\neg(A\land B)=\neg A\lor \neg B\\\neg(A\lor B)=\neg A\land\neg B$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use De Morgan's laws:

$$\neg(a \land b) = \neg a \lor \neg b \quad\quad \neg(a \lor b) = \neg a \land \neg b$$

So we have:

$$\neg((p \land (q \lor r)) \lor(\neg p\lor\neg q \lor r)) = $$

$$\neg(p \land (q \lor r)) \land \neg(\neg p\lor\neg q \lor r) = $$
$$(\neg p \lor \neg (q \lor r)) \land (\neg(\neg p\lor\neg q) \land \neg r) = $$
$$(\neg p \lor (\neg q \land \neg r)) \land (( p\land q) \land \neg r) = $$
$$((\neg p \lor (\neg q \land \neg r)) \land  p) \land q \land \neg r$$

We now use the distributive law $a \land (b \lor c) = (a\land b)\lor (a\land c)$:
$$(\neg p \land  p \lor (\neg q \land \neg r\land  p)) \land q \land \neg r = $$

$x \land \neg x$ is always false ($\bot$), and $\bot \lor x = x$:

$$\neg q \land \neg r\land  p \land q \land \neg r = $$

$$p \land \neg q \land  q \land \neg r = $$
$$p \land \bot \land \neg r = $$
$$\bot$$